# Taking a user imputed comparison operator directly into if statement (java)

Tags: java, compare, comparison

Sorry if this is a simple issue I am new to coding and couldn't find the answer anywhere online/couldn't find the right way to word it.

So I am taking in user input for a comparison operator (==, !=, <, <=,  >, >=) and then using it to figure out output.

Is it possible to directly put a user input into a if statement's comparison operator?

aka input userInputComparison and have if statement working?

```
if(number1 userInputComparison number2) {

}
```

Is there anther way to do it?

For example would it be possible to remove the redundancy in the below simplified version of my code?

```
BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String userInput = reader.readLine(); //Should be > or <
int userInputNumber = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
System.out.println("RESULTS");
int[] numbers = {5, 15, 12, 7, 0};
if (userInput.equals(">")) {
   for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      if(numbers[i] > userInputNumber) {
         System.out.println(numbers[i]);
      }
   }
} else if (userInput.equals("<")) {
   for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      if(numbers[i] < userInputNumber) {
         System.out.println(numbers[i]);
      }
   }
} else {
   System.out.println("please enter > or <");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly injecting pieces of user input into your source code and have it run is *very bad*. It implies that a user can now run any code on your computer, which is a big security risk.

Instead, you should keep your `if` statements, so that only `>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=` are allowed. The for loops inside though, *can* be extracted out, so you have less duplicate code.

You do this by storing the operator in a `BiPredicate<Integer, Integer>`:

```
BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> operator = (x, y) -> false;
if (userInput.equals(">")) {
   operator = (x, y) -> x > y;
} else if (userInput.equals("<")) {
   operator = (x, y) -> x < y;
} else if

...

} else {
   System.out.println("please enter > or <");
}
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   if(operator.test(numbers[i], userInputNumber)) {
      System.out.println(numbers[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Just a small thing: the BiFunction needs 3 arguments (first 2 for x,y and one for result) and `operator.apply(x,y)`. If you wanted to use the `operator.test()` I'm assuming that the correct interface should be `BiPredicate`

Comment: Should it no be a ```BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Boolean>``` or a ```BiPredicate<Integer,Integer>```?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use ScriptEngineManager from java. Here is a sample code to show you how to use it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByExtension("js");
    Bindings bindings = scriptEngine.createBindings();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter operator:");
    String userInput = reader.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter number:");
    int userInputNumber = reader.nextInt();

    int[] numbers = {5, 15, 12, 7, 0};

    String expression = "a" + userInput + "b";
    bindings.put("b", userInputNumber);

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        bindings.put("a", numbers[i]);
        if ((Boolean) scriptEngine.eval(expression, bindings)) {
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I prefer to use `Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader` for system console interactions. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/bufferedreader-vs-console-vs-scanner-in-java) are some good explanations for where you should use them.